# ambiguous overloaded function differs only by argument's template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, sfinae, ambiguous-call

Consider the following code:

```
SmartPointer<Data> Fix(SmartPointer<Data> data)
{
    return { /* Fixed Data */ };
}
SmartPointer<Data> Fix(SmartPointer<DataWrapper> dataWrapper)
{
    return Fix(dataWrapper->Data());    
}
```

How would I rewrite this so that it does not cause  "error C2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function" ?

Note: I would like to be able to pass in a subclass for example `SmartPointer<SubclassOfDataWrapper>` as well, and have that resolve to the overloaded function of the superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint provided by [Guillaume Racicot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104697/guillaume-racicot), I came up with the following solution:

```
template<typename T>
SmartPointer<Data> Fix(SmartPointer<T> dataWrapper)
{
    // Note: only a subclass of DataWrapper would have the method ->Data()
    //            a subclass of Data would not have it (SFINAE principle)
    return Fix( dataWrapper->Data() );
}
template<>
SmartPointer<Data> Fix(SmartPointer<Data> data)
{
    return { /* Fixed Data */ };
}
```

Comment: To constraint the function correctly, you would have to do this: `std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().Data())>* = nullptr` as a second template parameter.

Comment: Here's an application of that constraint: https://godbolt.org/z/7EcmAL Note that I changed specialization to overloading to do it properly

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot c++11 does not have std::void_t and "attempting to use a member of a type" is listed as an SFINAE Type Error here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae

Comment: Indeed. [Here's a C++11 version](https://godbolt.org/z/e5U9GT). It casts to void instead of using `std::void_t`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot any reason for the cast to void? it seems to compile fine when I write `decltype(std::declval<T>().Data())* = nullptr`

Comment: I don't know which type `Data()` will return. If it's a reference, you cannot form a pointer to it, which will also sfinae out types that returns a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Check if a there is a template conversion operator in your smart pointer class.

More importantly, check if there's something to SFINAE-out the conversion operator in case the conversion is invalid.

A static assert inside the conversion operator won't tell the compiler these overload are not ambiguous.

Comment: I see... so if I have a method specific to DataWrapper (i.e. `->Data()`) then I can use that to leverage SFINAE. I feel we are getting closer to the answer now.